# Is it possible to speed up pandas from_records?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading

I'm trying to load a very big numpy array (where all columns are different sized strings) and pandas `.from_records` takes about 10 seconds to complete.

I was wondering if it is possible to speed this process up? maybe mutli-threading / using more CPU cores?

Is that even supported with pandas?
Thank you.